# Is there a standard or open-source tag cloud implementation for SWT?

Tags: java, swt, tag-cloud

I need functionality for displaying and allowing selections of tags in SWT. Something that uses space efficiently, and ideally allows scaling of tags.

Is there a tag cloud widget or is there one that is easily available?

The closest that I've been able to come to a tag cloud manually and without too much work is to use a row layout with a button per each tag, but then to merely place a number next to each tag. If I tried to adjust size based on frequency, I would end up with too much open space because each row would have the vertical space of its latest tag. I'm assuming that a tag cloud implementation would use a more specialized layout.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe OpenCloud can move you in the right direction:

http://opencloud.sourceforge.net/

While not swt specific, it is Java and Tag-Cloud specific.

Good Luck.